# Python: compare multiple columns in same CSV

Tags: python, csv, compare, multiple-columns

I have a CSV with 400 columns; where i need to compare the elements of columns

```
COL[3] vs COL[4];
COL[5] vs COL[6];
----------
;;;
COL[399] vs col [400]
```

### Sample csv

```
id,base_1,current_1,base2,current_2
1,abc,abc,xyz,zyx
```

if a drift is noticed, then i need the header of the 2nd column. In above example columns 3 and 4 are unequal in that case I need the header "current_2"
Any thoughts for achieving this in a easier way?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your code that does not work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a longer `sample.csv` and also show what your expected output for that sample would be.